# How to delete express session cookie

Tags: mongodb, session, cookies, express

I am using express session and mongo connect for user auth, which is used by an angular client via CORS request.

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'xxxxxx',
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: 'dbname',
        clear_interval: 3600,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017
    })
}));
```

The login works fine and the cookie is dropped and session all works as expected.

My problem is with ending the session. I have a logout route, which essentially does this:

```
req.session.destroy(function() {
    // log out code
});
```

However in mongo db.sessions, the session still exists, and the sid cookie still remains on the user agent, so if the user revisits any "protected" URLs after logging out the session is regenerated.

So it looks like I need to either remove the cookie or remove the session from the db, the latter seems wrong, so I am trying to remove the cookie, but no luck, tried this in Express:

```
req.session.destroy(function() {
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
});
```

and it appears I can't delete the sid cookie on the client with javascript since it is http only (??) this didn't work:

```
document.cookie = 'connect.sid=; path=/; domain=localhost; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

any ideas how to get rid of this annoying session cookie??!

Answer (score 5):

`req.session.destroy()` should clear the session in the db.

Express is probably using a different sessionID when trying to destroy the session. Make sure `Session.prototype.destroy` is actually pulling the correct `this.id` that matches the id in `mongodb.sessions`.

I just came across this issue and it was because my request to the server to log out the user wasn't containing a session cookie (Had left out `withCredentials`).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url/auth/logout',
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

This caused express to generate a new session id for the request and asked mongodb to remove a session with that new id (leaving the old one untouched).